# Foreach loop prints only one name instead of several

Tags: php

Here I've written my code in the search.php file

```
if(isset($_POST['searchField'])){
    $searchName = UserManager::searchName();
    if(empty($_POST['searchField'])){
        $error = 'Typ a name';
    }else{
        if(!isset($_POST['searchName'])){
                $error = 'No result';
            } else{
                foreach($searchName as $name){
                    $succes = $name['firstName'] . " ". $name['lastName'];
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Here is a part of the HTML where it prints the full names.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php if(isset($error)): ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $error; ?>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(isset($succes)): ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $succes; ?>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

Here is my function:

```
public static function searchName()
 {
    $conn = Db::getConnection();

    $searchField = $_POST['searchField'];

    $statement = ("SELECT * from tl_user WHERE firstname = :name OR lastname = :name");

    $query = $conn->prepare($statement);

    $query->bindValue(':name', $searchField);
    //var_dump($searchField);

    $query->execute();
    //"SELECT * from tl_user WHERE firstName LIKE '%$searchName% OR lastName LIKE '%$searchName%"

    $count = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($count);
    return $count;
 }
```

My question exactly is: if there are more people with the same lastName, it prints only 1 full name instead of several names.

In my function I've put 'var_dump($count);' to see if there is more than 1 array and there is, but it doesn't print

I'm a beginner, so I'm still learning :)

Comment: you are overriding your `$success` var at each loop run

Comment: What can I do about that? :/

Comment: I don't know, this is your code, not mine... You may print the array directly inside your loop or build an array in the loop to later print it (although I don't see the point to get an array and build a second one just to print it later)

Comment: you can use `array_push` in the iteration so that  it will add the results that you get from `$success` to an array which is defined before the  iteration begin. And also you can concatenate the values that you get in the iteration as well.

Answer (score 1):

concatenate values into `$succes` using `.=` rather than overwriting it each time round the loop

```
$succes = '';
foreach($searchName as $name){
    $succes .= $name['firstName'] . " ". $name['lastName'];
}
```

Comment: I've put this in my code. Now I get several names! Thanks! But it gives an error: 'Undefined variable: succes' on that line

Comment: If you are using `.=` concatenation, the `$succes` var has to be initialised before first use.

Comment: See amended answer

Comment: Now it's gone and it's working! Thank you for the help!!